# Spring4D - When registering a type with a container is it possible to specify only the arguments you want to override in InjectConstructor()?

Tags: delphi, dependency-injection, spring4d

Given a type and registration of

```
      TTest = class
      public
        constructor Create(First, Second: IO; Other: TOther);
      end;

  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TOther,TOther>;
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IO,TO1>.AsDefault;
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<IO,TO2>('Second');
```

As I want to override the second parameter I have to

```
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TTest>.InjectConstructor([nil,'Second',nil]);
```

I want to only override the second argument.  I understand for argument placement I would also have to specify the first argument but as I add further and further constructor arguments I have to keep remembering to go back and modify the registration.

It would be easier to

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TTest>.InjectConstructor([nil,'Second']);
```

rather than

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TTest>.InjectConstructor([nil,'Second',nil,nil,nil,nil]);
```

as I add further dependencies as surely nil could be implied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible via the registration API but I have this on my list of things I want to implement at some point. My idea is to do it very similar to how [autofac](https://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html) does it  - no eta though I am afraid.

However, you can place an `[Inject('second')]` on the `Second` parameter of the `TTest` constructor to achieve this (remember to put `Spring.Container.Common` into the uses to make the attribute work).